# I know the carousel using is not user friendly but are Instagram stories different?

Tags: usability, carousel, user-generated-content

I know the carousel using is not user-friendly but why Instagram stories working like hell? It's a similar component. It has a lot of usability issues. When we use stories we don't know what we'll see. Same as carousels in the web pages.

I wonder why it is working? I don't like the format but I got used to watching either.

Maybe It is working because users know Instagram's stories concept. It is mostly random content which is created by users. The carousels in the websites mostly give an offer which is not related to our interests. And users developed a banner blindness.

What do you think about this?

Comment: Unfortunately there's no way for us to know why this works for Instagram without carrying out a study testing various users' responses to various carousel formats, lengths, and interaction devices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The traditional notion of "carousels not working" only seems to be applied to the scenario were stakeholders want to push a lot of marketing content in a confined space, resulting in the dredged Homepage and Landing Page carousels.

However, "carousels" are a completely valid interface choice for other purposes. Think about e-commerce product photo galleries, or photo previews in Windows, MacOS and any other photo management application. It is a completely valid option for people to browse content.

So back to Instagram. Different context, different use, different application, different scenario. Therefore most of the "carousels not working" points don't apply here. Since, as proven, stories are working rather well.

The "carousels not working" studies were based on studies analyzing Homepages, Landing Pages, marketing content. Therefore it's recommendations should only be applied to those scenarios, not everything that can be defined as a "carousel".